# Too many EC2 fleet resources recorded in AWS Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, aws-config

In AWS Config there are 63k recorded EC2 Fleet resources. Config that I currently have is 1 EKS cluster with 6 node groups and 17 nodes. I don't have any other instances running.

[image]

Is this correct? And if not - how can I track what is the problem here?

Comment: First, are you using Karpenter and have you enabled consolidation? I believe that Config looks at EKS and non-EKS instances. That might account for the high number relative to the nodes in your cluster.